# findViewById returns null for layout in dependency

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have an app A that uses a library C. Library C contains an Activity that requires a resource from library D.

I would expect the resources from D to be bundled into C, but get a null when doing `findViewById(R.id.resource_from_d)` within C. How can I get this to work?

C does not have the default project structure , but C does not contain any resources itself. And I specified 
`sourceSets { main { java.srcDirs = ['src'] }}` in the build.gradle for C.

I also have proguard and minifyEnabled set to false to avoid any resources from bein erroneously removed.

I also tried setting transitive = true for all of the transitive dependencies, but no luck. What can I do to get this to work?

This is the build.gradle of C, which depends on the resources of D.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    compileOptions.encoding = 'windows-1252'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':d')
}
```

The project structure of C is not the default, hence why I added the sourceSets for the sources. C does not contain any resources of its own, though.

Comment: did you import the right `R`? or tried to use it directly like `com.dpackage.R`?

Comment: I import the R from A not D. This works when building with maven, not sure why it does not work with gradle.

Comment: hum ok...I don't know why it's not working but it makes sense to me, why would you expect to find D's ids inside A's R?

Comment: I use both IDs from A and D, so only import the R from D would not work either.

Comment: you can use both, you can import one with `import` and use the other calling the full name like `com.mydpackage.R.id.resource_from_d`

Comment: I am actually doing a super call from A's Activity.onCreate, which calls an onCreate in C. C has the import R of D, so that is correct. But it cannot find the layout in D.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123142/discussion-between-barq-and-lelloman).

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to use both `R`s

```
import com.apackage.R;

//...

int aResource = R.id.resource_from_a;
int dResource = com.dpackage.R.id.resource_from_d;
```